# gcc linker fails with .a files and gtest

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker, ld

My makefile entry is:

`tests: testLib.a
    $(CC) testLib.a -o tests /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a -lpthread -Iinclude $(LD_FLAGS) $(CC_FLAGS)`

testLib.a is archive create with (currently) single .o file with tests created with makefile entry:

`testLib.a: test_obj $(TEST_OBJ_FILES)
    ar rvs testLib.a $(TEST_OBJ_FILES)`

And I receive linker error to gtest:

`` /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o): In function `main':
gtest_main.cc:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
/usr/lib/libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o): In function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
gtest_main.cc:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0x5): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
gtest_main.cc:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0xd): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

But when I change testLib.a to single .o file everything compiles fine:

`tests: testLib.a
    $(CC) test_obj/singleTestFile.o -o tests /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a -lpthread -Iinclude $(LD_FLAGS) $(CC_FLAGS)`

What's wrong with my entries that they don't work with self created archives? ar gets file correctly from `$(TEST_OBJ_FILES)`:

`ar rvs testLib.a test_obj/singleTestFile.o`

Comment: Link order matters.

Comment: Just realized that when I move `/usr/lib/libgtest_main.a` to beginning, everything works fine

Comment: But do you know *why*? If not, you should find out.

Comment: I don't, but I see moving it to beginning made gtest blind for tests from `testLib.a`. Again everything works fine if I change it to .o file.

Comment: Hint: symbols needed by an object  must be seen by the linker before objects providing them. Otherwise. They will just be discarded as unneeded.